# How to integrate undetected chrome driver for windows application

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, winappdriver, appium-desktop, undetected-chromedriver

We are automating the windows application using appium - selenium and winappdriver. Before performing any action in our application we need to login with Microsoft account. For login with Microsoft account, our windows application supports chromedriver. So, while we click on "Login with Microsoft account" automatically chrome browser supports. Here how we need to integrate the undetected chrome driver?

After click on "Login with Microsoft account", login pop up is loading blank

Comment: you can check the link here https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/issues/144. While I said undetected-chromedriver is an option that could work, microsoft probably is aware of it.